# Getting Position of a Player in a grid

Tags: c++, sfml, grid, visual-studio

So I am making a pacman-like game. the game has tiles/grid. I keep the node data in a struct:

```
struct Node

{
    std::pair <int, int> node; // position of the node <x,y>
    float f = 0,
          h = 0,
          g = 0;
    std::pair <int, int> previous; 
    bool iswall = false;
    sf::Vector2f rectCenter = sf::Vector2f(0, 0);
    sf::Vector2f position;

};
```

i use the struct to calculate a path, check if the cell is an obstacle (or not) etc.

now in the main I use the arrays and a for loop to draw the grid:

```
for (int i = 0; i<col; i++)
        for (int j = 0; j < row; j++)
        {
            /*default color is black*/
            box[i][j].setFillColor(sf::Color::Black);
            box[i][j].setOutlineColor(sf::Color::Yellow);
            box[i][j].setOutlineThickness(-1);
            box[i][j].setSize(sf::Vector2f(w, h));  
            box[i][j].setPosition(sf::Vector2f(i*w, j*h));
            sf::FloatRect fbox = box[i][j].getGlobalBounds();
        }
```

[[image][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lofPB.png)

I also use the strcut to create specific nodes (current position, start node, end node)

and i draw it in the man like this:

```
        //displays the start node as green
        if (i == crntNodex && j == crntNodey)
        {
            box[i][j].setFillColor(sf::Color::Green);
                }
```

now the problem that I'm facing is making a function that can get the current node that the player (blue square on the green cell) is. My attempt for this was checking if the cell contained the player

```
std::pair<int, int> AIEnemy::getNodePosition(sf::RectangleShape * grid, int i, int j)
{

    if (box.contains(rect.getPosition().x, rect.getPosition().y))
    {
         return std::pair<int, int>(i,j);
    }
}
```

but It is not efficient (and also doesn't update). is there a way I can get game objects coord on a grid?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your player is at (x, y) where both coordinates are in pixels, and you know that the width pf a tile is `w` pixels, then you can get the position by simply doing

```
posX = floor(x / w)
posY = floor(y / w)
```

Comment: thank you very much for the response it works. and if anybody else is seeing this for

posY its posY = floor(y / h)

Comment: @YamaraiAkizuki if the answer solved your problem, press the tick button

Comment: sorry still getting used to this